# Using Bookshelfjs with REST API Data

Tags: bookshelf.js

My App is fully driven based on API and would like to try bookshelf model collection, is their any  anexample related to this, would like to know how its structured , validating properties, setting default values and fetching data.

Currently i use `npm request` to call API and the have simple object model to map.

Would like to replace current implementation with bookself.